# SVG image is not loading in canvas in Mozilla browser

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, svg, mozilla

SVG image is not loading in canvas in Mozilla browser but the save code is working fine in Chrome.
I attached my code here. Please check and let me know the solution.

```
var canvasProduct = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctxProduct = canvasProduct.getContext('2d');    
var newproductSvg = '<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 354.11 205.65">.....</svg>
    var imageObj = new Image();    
    imageObj.onload = function() {
                ctxProduct.drawImage(imageObj,0,0,100,100);
                console.log("Shadow image loaded");
            }
    imageObj.src = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,"+newproductSvg;
```

Here is svg data :

```
<svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 376.94">
                                                <defs>
                                                    <style>
                                                    .cls-2 {
                                                        fill: #1e73be;
                                                    }
                                                    </style>
                                                </defs>
                                                <title>crewNeck Tshirt</title>
                                                <path class="cls-2" d="M80.16,372.86c1.81-21.51,2.63-43.09,3.14-64.65.37-15.66,1.46-31.28,1.73-47,.45-25.59.13-51.24,2.52-76.78.52-5.58.92-11.19,1.12-16.79a30.28,30.28,0,0,1,6.09-17.16c2.05-2.82.26-5.66-.38-8.17s-3.29-.81-4.88-.34c-15.57,4.57-32,5-47.42,10.4-2.09.73-4.12,1.16-5.62-1.35-11.8-19.69-25.69-38.14-34.94-59.32-.4-.92-.74-1.86-1.06-2.81-1-2.91-.56-4.75,2.59-6.55,6.25-3.56,12.2-7.58,19.56-8.52a3.87,3.87,0,0,0,1.55-.61c16.7-10.87,34.36-20,51.69-29.81,18.15-10.23,38-15.12,57.74-20.57,9.94-2.75,19.78-5.88,29.64-8.94,1.42-.44,2.69-.84,4.15-.29C187,21,206.46,20.18,225.81,12.57c2-.79,4-1.58,6.24-.54,11.9,5.61,24.74,7.88,37.51,10.25,22.42,4.16,43.69,11.66,64.41,21,7.05,3.18,14.84,5.06,21.33,9.07,13,8,28.47,8.4,41.91,14.78,2.75,1.3,3.43,2.26,2.22,5.27a375,375,0,0,1-18.94,40.94A219.55,219.55,0,0,0,369,137.41c-1.45,3.6-3.06,5.28-7.38,5.16-13.64-.38-27.29,1-41,.22-4.16-.23-8.27-1-12.48-.72-1.68.13-2.14.87-3.06,2.13-3.18,4.34-3.09,8.82-3.22,14.06-.34,14.66,3.28,28.78,4.25,43.22,1.38,20.52,3.69,41,4.91,61.5,1,17.65,3,35.25,3.83,52.92,1,21,1.87,42,1.58,63,0,2.58-.68,3.67-3.46,3.3-11.82-1.6-23.57.13-35.23,1.47-34.8,4-69.61,6.29-104.63,3.75-20.8-1.51-41.49-4.36-62.34-5-8.91-.29-17.85-.16-26.77,0-3.26.05-4.93-.57-4-4.32C80.51,376.4,80.16,374.58,80.16,372.86Z" transform="translate(0 -11.53)" />
                                            </svg>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here I have attached one of my sample svg code : http://prntscr.com/e9wapk

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you please check my sample svg ?

Comment: @RobertLongson : Actually I just put some dot here in my post. Please check the screen shot for the full svg data. http://prnt.sc/e9wapk

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467468/embedded-background-svg-doesnt-display-on-firefox-if-it-has-a-fill-attribute/25470044#25470044

Comment: Posting a picture of your SVG code is silly.  Please post it in your question instead.  Or better still, create an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau : I have added the svg data into my question. Please check and let me know if you need anything more information.

Comment: @RobertLongson : I have replaced it with '%23'. But same issue.

Comment: But this sample code working fine in Chrome browser.

Comment: @RobertLongson : How can I put width,height ? Like this <svg data-name="Layer 1" width="250" height="250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 302.54 400">.... ?

Comment: @RobertLongson : thanks for your solution.. It's working now.. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've two separate problems.

1. the root `<svg>` element needs explicit width and height attributes that are not percentages
2. the # character is a reserved character in a URL and must be escaped as %23

---

1. It's not clear what should happen with an infinite canvas displaying an infinitely sized shape so Firefox does not currently support this. If the w3c provided a clear definition of what's supposed to happen it could be implemented. I'm not sure what Chrome does in this case.
2. Is a Chrome bug. It may give you what you want in this case but it's still wrong per the appropriate specifications.