# How to get .svg image from url, modify paths inside and set the image back at the css "background-image" property?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, background-image

I am struggling to find a working way to achive my goal here, so after hours of research I am trying to ask you here. Also I am still a beginner in Javascript / Css matters.

Situation:

I am having a html webpage which contains a div. This div has a background-image set through css, like this:

```
style="background-image: url("Media/tux.svg"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;"
```

What I need to do now in my Javascript code is to modify the color ("fill") of some of the paths inside this image, so that I can see these changes on the image on the webpage.

I have found a way to grab the contents of the image by doing something like this:

```
var mySvg;
$.get("Media/tux.svg", function (data) {
    mySvg = data;
}, 'xml')
```

After this, "mySvg" contains a huge -tag with the contents of my image. I am then able to find one certain path and modify its "fill" attribute by doing the following:

```
$(mySvg).find("#path3205:first").css("fill", "#FFFFFF");
```

But the problem now is, how do i get this variable back to my "background-image" css property?

There are some ways mentioned on stackoverflow / google which i have tried. The latest i tried was taken from this jsfiddle file. Here i took the "url" part and tried to apply it to my div, but still i dont see any changes on my background image.

https://jsfiddle.net/estelle/SJjJb/

If you know a working way to do this, it would be great. Thank you very much.

If you need further information, please let me know.

Best regards.

Comment: Try to replace # to %23. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467468/embedded-background-svg-doesnt-display-on-firefox-if-it-has-a-fill-attribute/25470044#25470044